# UWP Start audio from backgorund

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I have UWP application which has option of voip calls.
When the call is received, ringtone is played using MediaPlayer.

Problem is when app is in background because if call is received then ringtone is not played.

I looked into documentation, e.g. [Play media in the background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio), but it only mentions scenarios when audio starts playing while app is in foreground and continues playing when app is moved to background.

Is there a way to play audio when app is already in background?

I even tried to start playing audio with 0 volume while app is still in foreground and increase volume to 1 when call is received in background. That worked but then I have transport controls shown all the time when screen is locked.

Comment: How do you plan to play audio in the background? After entering the background, we have no user interface, so in what way do you prepare to trigger background playback?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT When I get websocket message about incoming call I call Play method of MediaPlayer. I'm not sure why would I need any user interface for it.

Comment: MediaPlayer can only play in the foreground, if you want to play in the background, you need to use backgroundMediaPlayback. In addition, you could try to use ToastNotification, when the call is received, show the toast and you can also add the audio in toast.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I already tried with adding backgroundMediaPlayback capability but it didn't help. I also tried to use BackgroundMediaPlayer but that didn't work too. In the end I used ToastNotification which can play audio while app is in background. Thanks for the suggestion.